Alt-H Not unhiding anything at all
I hid most of my 11k objects scene using shift-H, then alt-H didn't work. I could unhide them manually in the outliner but that's not really smooth if they are so many. Apparently you also cannot select them with A in the outliner.
I found no viable answer online, it probably has something to do with wild parenting/nesting/linking going.

...or you are in Local view (Numpad /)? Usually Alt+H does not care about parenting etc. But it cannot unhide objects that are disabled in viewport (the monitor icon in the Outliner), only the ones hidden in viewport (the eye icon).

hard to say without the file, maybe you were in Local view as Gordon says

@moonboots I actually guess they are disabled in viewport. Unfortunately there is no "unhide" for that in Blender...

Anyway, this script will unhide all objects in the currently selected collection:
import bpy

# Get the active collection from the currently selected context
context = bpy.context
selected_collection = context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection

if selected_collection:
    # Loop through all objects in the active collection
    for obj in selected_collection.objects:
        # Unhide the object
        obj.hide_set(False)
        obj.hide_viewport = False
        obj.hide_render = False
    print(f"All objects in the collection '{selected_collection.name}' have been unhidden.")
else:
    print("No collection is currently selected.")
```


If you really want to make sure everything is visible again, your script solution is probably the best since Blender unfortunately only has a function to unhide all objects set to Hide in Viewport (the eye icon in the Outliner) but there is no equivalent to make objects visible that are set to Disable in Viewport (the monitor icon).
However, as an alternative - for example if you do not really want to make everything visible again, just certain objects but do not want to search in all collections or parent hierarchies to find all that are hidden - you can use the filter for the Outliner.
Just click on the Filter option (the funnel icon) and under Filter you can switch All to Visible and then use the Invert toggle (the double arrow icon $\leftrightarrow$). This only shows objects which are not visible in the viewport - no matter if hidden or disabled and even when they are parented to something.
The only thing that might still hide them is the hierarchies not being expanded so either press Numpad + in the Outliner to expand to the next level or Shift+A to expand all levels.
This way you can just go down the list of hidden objects and decide which ones you want to make visible again - and what kind of visibility.
